# FBJS/FBML: Display a textbox on click of radio button

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

I want to use FBML as a canvas and would like to display a textbox on click of radio button.
Can anybody out there help me out on this? e.g. if a user selects other as option it should make appear a text box. Is it possible? how? I'm eager to learn more from the responder.

Comment: Good old Ctrl+L lowercase hotkey helps :D

Comment: very imprecise n illicit answers

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible .
Step 1 : make a div and put text box code into that div , and assign any id to the div let say  id ="textbox". and in style attribute to the div put display='none' and call below function on onclick of the radio input

```
function showBoxt(id)
  {
      obj=document.getElementById(id);
            if(obj.getStyle('display')=='none')
             {
                    obj.setStyle({display:'block'});
             }
            else
              {
                obj.setStyle({display:'none'});
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i was just looking for the answer for this question as well.
and i found a [useful link here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=87666).

thought i might share it.
i've tried and tested, the animation just makes it look slicker :)

```
function showdiv(id){
        var elm = document.getElementById(id);
        if(elm.getStyle('display') == 'block'){
            Animation(elm).to('height', '0px').to('opacity', 0).hide().ease(Animation.ease.end).go(); 
            return false;
        }else{
            Animation(elm).to('height', 'auto').to('opacity', 1).show().ease(Animation.ease.end).go(); 
            return false;
        }
    }

<div id="about" style="display: none"> 
Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. 
People use Facebook to keep up with friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, share links and videos, and 
learn more about the people they meet. 
</div> 
<a href="#" onclick="showdiv('about');">Show Content</a>.
```